# Detect what the compilation debug flag is set at from code?

Tags: asp.net

Is there any easy way to tell what debug attribute of the compilation tag is currently set at in code?

Why do i want to do this? So i can switch from between minified/Non-Minified versions of javascript/css. The following is what i've tried (which didn't work):

```
public  function GetLink(byval url As String) As String
    Static isDebugEnabled As Nullable(Of Boolean)

    If isDebugEnabled Is Nothing Then
        isDebugEnabled = New System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection().Debug
    End If

    If isDebugEnabled.Value OrElse  Regex.IsMatch(url,"\.min\.",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) Then
        return url
    Else 
        Dim cssOrJsFileName = Regex.Match(url,"/[a-z]+\.(css|js)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).
            ToString().
            Replace("/",String.Empty).
            Replace(".js",String.Empty).
            Replace(".css",String.Empty)

        return  url.Replace(cssOrJsFileName,cssOrJsFileName + ".min")
    End If

End Function


   <link href="<%: getlink("/includes/styles/csssharedbundle.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<%: getlink("/includes/styles/csssite.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The code above is always returning the minified file no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  Or at least, that's not the best way to do it.

Use [preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) to accomplish this.

```
#if DEBUG
//return non-minified
#else
//return minified
#endif
```

I believe they are available and have the same syntax as your moon language.  Consult the link to be sure.